# Convert timeunits to timestamps

Tags: r, timestamp, simulation

I did a simulation with simmer and I got an event log. The start and end of an activity are represented as time units.
they look as follows:

```
|   start   |    end    |
| --------- | --------  |
|  5.658733 | 13.244381 |
| 11.342792 | 13.583395 |
| 12.000000 | 13.612889 |
| 14.000000 | 14.000000 |
...
| 2694.162  | 6699.370  |
```

I would like to convert these in timestamps. For that, I would like to determine an exact time and date of time at which the simulation started and convert all the following time units accordingly to timestamps that look like "2020-01-02 11:23:00".
I set the simulation to run until time unit 2700

```
run(until=2700)
```

As far as I understand this means the simulation runs for 1 week (7 days).

Comment: Hi ncnc_2020, I am not a DES/simmer expert, but to my knowledge "process time" (or step in your simulation) is given by the context. Thus, 2700 "steps" are dependent on your simulation setup or problem you model. When I take a week, then 2700 steps would be equivalent to (7 * 24 * 60 * 60) / 2700 = 224 seconds. That feels a bit weird for a "unit step time". Adapt below to your problem. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is to help you getting started. I am not a DES/simmer expert. But what I understand is that the activity log gives you start and end times (in your simulation) of specific activities.

I am not fully sure how "simulation units" of 2700 account for a week. But you may calculate your "simulation time step" based on this.

For a start, I assume the given activity start and end "units" are minutes.

**reproducible data for activity log**

```
library(dplyr)  # tidyverse data frame handling

log <- tibble::tribble(
  ~start,       ~end
  ,5.658733, 13.244381
  ,11.342792, 13.583395
  ,12.000000, 13.612889
  ,14.000000, 14.000000
  ,2694.162 ,6699.370
  )
```

**convert units in time durations**

As mentioned above this is where you have to think about converting your "simulation units" into time durations. That will influence the factor with which you have to multiply your values to convert them into timeunits of measurement.

A package to help with converting double to durations is `{hms}`.

```
library(hms)

## check out what hms does
as_hms(log$start)
00:00:05.658733
00:00:11.342792
00:00:12.000000
00:00:14.000000
00:44:54.162000
```

`{hms}` converts your `double-simulation-step-units` into seconds.

I am assuming that your activity times / simulation step time is in minutes.
Thus, we need to multiply with 60.

Please note that you need to choose the respective conversion here. For example, your 2700 simulation time units could be 1 week = 7 days = 7 * 24 hr = 7 * 24 * 60 * 60 sec. Then your conversion would be (7 * 24 * 60 * 60) / 2700. But I leave this to you to verify and adapt.

```
log <- log %>% mutate(
  start_moment = as_hms(start * 60)
, end_moment   = as_hms(end * 60)
)

log
# A tibble: 5 x 4
    start    end start_moment   end_moment     
    <dbl>  <dbl> <time>         <time>         
1    5.66   13.2 00:05:39.52398  00:13:14.66286
2   11.3    13.6 00:11:20.56752  00:13:35.00370
3   12      13.6 00:12:00.00000  00:13:36.77334
4   14      14   00:14:00.00000  00:14:00.00000
5 2694.   6699.  44:54:09.72000 111:39:22.20000
```

**adding durations to start-time**

The rest is as you suggested, add your converted duration to your simulation start time. For example:

```
library(lubridate) # for date-time operations

sim_start <- lubridate::ymd_hms("2020-01-02 11:23:00")  # define your sim start

log <- log %>% 
  mutate(
     start_time = sim_start + start_moment
   , end_time   = sim_start + end_moment
)
```

This yields

```
log
# A tibble: 5 x 6
    start    end start_moment   end_moment      start_time          end_time           
    <dbl>  <dbl> <time>         <time>          <dttm>              <dttm>             
1    5.66   13.2 00:05:39.52398  00:13:14.66286 2020-01-02 11:28:39 2020-01-02 11:36:14
2   11.3    13.6 00:11:20.56752  00:13:35.00370 2020-01-02 11:34:20 2020-01-02 11:36:35
3   12      13.6 00:12:00.00000  00:13:36.77334 2020-01-02 11:35:00 2020-01-02 11:36:36
4   14      14   00:14:00.00000  00:14:00.00000 2020-01-02 11:37:00 2020-01-02 11:37:00
5 2694.   6699.  44:54:09.72000 111:39:22.20000 2020-01-04 08:17:09 2020-01-07 03:02:22
```

Obviously, the aforementioned logic is simple and you may need to add different times to your durations.

For example, if the start of the subsequent activity (step) follows after the previous step, you need to start creating calculating the endtime and use this for the next step as start_time, etc. This was unfortunately not clear from your question.

But with the conversion to durations, you should have the building block to get you going.

Comment: Thank you! This helped a lot! Do you know any function that would help me to do the contrary of this? Convert timestamps to doubles where I define my own 0?

Comment: Great to hear that my answer helped you getting going. For timestamp to doubles, try the following with library(lubridate); library(hms); period_to_seconds(hms("12:12:54")).